# density function of $\frac{1}{\left(X+Y\right)^{2}+1}$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

X and Y are independent continuous random variables with the same density function. Find the density function of $\frac{1}{\left(X+Y\right)^{2}+1}$.

I have tried getting the Jacobian where T maps (x,y) to (u,v) by

u = $\frac{1}{\left(X+Y\right)^{2}+1}$,  $\ v = x $

and $\ T^{-1}$ maps (u,v) to (x,y) by

x = v, $y=\sqrt{\frac{1}{u}-1}$

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\pp\pars{Z}
&=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dd X\,{\rm P}\pars{X}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dd Y
\,{\rm P}\pars{Y}\,\delta\pars{Z - {1 \over \pars{X + Y}^{2} + 1}}
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dd X\,{\rm P}\pars{X}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dd Y
\,{\rm P}\pars{Y}\times
\\[3mm]&\Theta\pars{Z}\Theta\pars{1 - Z}\braces{%
{\delta\pars{Y - \bracks{X - \root{\pars{1 - Z}/Z}}} \over 2Z\root{Z\pars{1 - Z}}}
+
{\delta\pars{Y - \bracks{X + \root{\pars{1 - Z}/Z}}} \over 2Z\root{Z\pars{1 - Z}}}}
\\[3mm]&=
{\Theta\pars{Z}\Theta\pars{1 - Z} \over 2Z\root{Z\pars{1 - Z}}}\braces{%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm P}\pars{X}\bracks{%
{\rm P}\pars{X - \root{1 - Z \over Z}}
+
{\rm P}\pars{X + \root{1 - Z \over Z}}}\,\dd X}
\end{align}